# Issue with jQuery Menu Links

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to implement this jQuery Menu that I found on the Internet:
http://spyrestudios.com/coding-a-horizontal-navigation-bar-with-jquery-dropdown-menus/

For some reason this doesn't allow links to URL's.

http://www.virtualpetstore.com/

I've tried to remove e.preventDefault from the script but that doesn't work either.

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/4m7Q2/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   });

$('#ddmenu li').hover(function () {
 clearTimeout($.data(this,'timer'));
 $('ul',this).stop(true,true).slideDown(200);
}, function () {
$.data(this,'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
  $('ul',this).stop(true,true).slideUp(200);
}, this), 100));
});

});
```

I was wondering if anyone has a clue about what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('li:has(ul) > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the target of the link to '_blank', and probably remove the e.preventDefault(). For example:

`<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Our Mission</a>`

New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4m7Q2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your page and ran this in the console and then the links worked fine.

```
$('a').unbind('click');
```

It seems that the preventDefault is definitely what's eating your links.

Comment: For some reason this guy had this in his build.